# GAE Datastore entity for private messages

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to create an Android app in which users could only communicate by sending private messages to their friends. I am using java for my GAE application.

More precisely, if user A has three friends B, C and D, I want him to be able to select two of them (lets say B and C) and initiate a thread that D could not see. In that thread, A B and C could talk in an asynchronous way like in forums.

The question is: how to make my entities to meet those criteria in the most efficient way?

For now, I figured I would need two entities: thread and message. But for instance I don't know where should I add the reference to B and C when A will send the request of thread in the datastore. If I add it in a field Recipients as a List of users, I think it would be too long for a user to request all of the threads he is invited on.

I know what I want to do is quite classic, so can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

```
class User(ndb.Model):
  pass

class Thread(ndb.Model):
  participants = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User, repeated=True)

class Message(ndb.Model):
  thread = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Thread)
  user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)

# user's thread
Thread.query(Thread.participants == user.key).fetch()

# all thread messages
Message.query(Message.thread == thread.key).fetch()
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am using Java. I will edit my question.

Comment: Ok thank you, but I don't understand Python. Hopefully someone can convert your code in Java.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard at all to find the equivalent [data models](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities) and [query forms](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries) in Java using the documentation. Feel free to make use of the documentation available for any software system you're working with, it will surely aid your comprehension and allow you to even be the expert to your own questions! :)